# Load01,Load05,Load15 attributes in apache camel jmx returns empty string

Tags: apache-camel, jmx

I am using Apache Camel (v2.19.1) in a spring boot application. I want to monitor the application with JMX MBeans.

I want to find out the load for a particular 'route' from the class "org.apache.camel.management.mbean.ManagedRoute" attributes Load01, Load05 etc...

I get empty string as values for Load attributes. The statistics is already enabled.

Kindly help.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

You need to turn this on. You can find details in the JMX documentation how to turn on load statistics: http://camel.apache.org/camel-jmx.html, eg set the `loadStatisticsEnabled=true`

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, as mentioned in the question, the statistics somehow is enabled by default. I used Jconsole to mornitor the attributes of the Mbeans. Jconsole shows "StatisticsEnabled=true". Unless I am looking at wrong thing.

Comment: There is another option to turn on load only, eg *Load*Statistics. You need to turn that one also on.

Comment: Thank you, I managed to see some values in Load01, Load05, Load15 through the following code                                                                                                                             
DefaultCamelContext camelContext = (DefaultCamelContext) getContext();
    
    camelContext.getManagementStrategy().getManagementAgent().setStatisticsLevel(ManagementStatisticsLevel.RoutesOnly);
    camelContext.getManagementStrategy().getManagementAgent().setLoadStatisticsEnabled(true);

Comment: However the values for Load01 etc are negative numbers. And the numeric part keeps increasing even though there is no load. Appreciate any help.